# Typescript with React Hook Form and React-select Multiple selected value not submitted by the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using react hook form and react select with typescript . Its works fine for single selected value. But when I choose isMulti for multiple selected value , I am unable to get the value from the submitted form .
Here is the code

```
 interface ITopic {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}
```

...........

```
const topicOptions : ITopic[] = [
    { value: 'javascript', label: 'JAVASCRIPT' },
    { value: 'php', label: 'PHP' },
    { value: 'python', label: 'PYTHON' },
    { value: 'java', label:'JAVA' },
    { value: 'C#', label: 'C#' }
]

type TopicType = { label: string, value: string }

const [selectedTopic, setSelectedTopic] = useState<readonly ITopic[]>([]);
```

..........

```
<Controller
   control={control}
   render={({ field: { onChange, value, name, ref } }) =>{
   const handleSelectionChange = (topicOptions: readonly SelectOptionType[]) => {
   setSelectedTopic(topicOptions)
   console.log(selectedTopic)
  }
   return  (
      <Select
      isMulti
      name={name}
      value={selectedTopic}
      options={topicOptions} 
      onChange={handleSelectionChange}
      />
  )}}
  name="topics"
/>
```

I am getting empty topics value. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using `react-hook-form` to manage your form, you shouldn't in addition have `useState` for your variable.

What you want to do instead is to use `onChange` from the `Controller`'s `render` method.

For instance, my multi select code is (assuming `topicOptions` is an array of `TopicType: { label:string; value:string }`)

```
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="topics"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <Select
            isMulti
            name="topics"
            options={topicOptions}
            value={topicOptions.filter((el) => value?.includes(el.value))}
            onChange={(option: TopicType[] | null) => {
              if (option === null) {
                onChange(null);

                return;
              }

              onChange(option.map((el) => el.value));
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: value={topicOptions.filter((el) => value?.includes(el.value))}
showing error 
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Comment: I fixed that never issue by in my default values  defaultValues: {topics:[""]}

Comment: Thanks a lot . Your answer is really helpful . 
Just need to modify few things , under <Controller
control={control}
 name={"topics"} // here I give the name and more importantly in the onChange it should be  (val: readonly {label:string; value:string;}[] | null) as  
https://react-select.com/typescript
documentation says, If you have a multi-select you can type onChange like this:

const onChange = (option: readonly Option[], actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => {
   ...
}

Comment: @PSA I edited my answer based on your comment. Glad my answer helped!

Comment: Yeah ! Just one thing , ... option: readonly Option[] , here Option[] is the type of the options .
Here for my topicOptions , I have used type TopicType = { label: string, value: string }. I have updated my question . You were right as you assumed topicOptions is an array of { label:string; value:string }).
Please update the answer with, Option[], with TopicType[], it will be helpful for the others .
Thank You again . Happy Coding  .